# Move dialog off the screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Using jQuery ui dialog, and needed  the dialog to move off the screen, 
Tried with

```
$.ui.dialog.prototype._makeDraggable = function() { 
this.uiDialog.draggable({
    containment: false,
    });
};
```

This works fine for left and top. But on moving to the right and bottom i get  scroll bars for the window which i do not want those to appear,  Is there any way that i can eliminate these?

Comment: did u try using a containment?

Comment: yeah, i've used the above code. and ve set the containment to false. dialog's moving off the screen well the too, but on dragging it to the right or bottom i get scrollbars for the window, which i want to avoid.is there any way to do this??

Comment: Are you able to move dialog out of browser window ? I am in trouble. Please reply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found out what was going wrong in here. This works absolutely the way i need it after i added this below code to the css

```
body {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: hidden;
}


html {
overflow-y: hidden;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

All i needed was to set the bottom and right as 0

Now it works like a charm:)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use containment for limiting the dragging.

Foe Ex,

```
$("#dialog").dialog().data("dialog").uiDialog.draggable("option","containment","body");
```

Please refer this: http://jsfiddle.net/aXWAj/

Comment: Actually i want the dialog to move off screen, and that's working fine, but the thing is i am window expands with scrollbars on dragging it to right or bottom, i want the dialog to go off screen but i do not want the scrollbars.

Comment: let me make it simple, in the above fiddle just change the "body" to "none" or "false" and then drag it to the left, i want it to work the same way when it's dragged to right, but there i get a scrollbar when i drag too much. why is it so?? maybe because they do not have a specific width??

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/pitchaip/aXWAj/17/   Now i have set the containment to document which allows to move over the document and  not extending the scroll

Comment: but still that doesn't solve my problem,it still stays on the screen, whereas i want to hide the dialog off the screen without scroll bars

Comment: you may need to add "overflow: hidden;" for the body and set the containment to false.

Comment: That hides the scrollbars, but it still keeps on moving without no definite boundry.is there any way so that i can restrict the body width and height to certain value??